# Flash/ActionScript: How to center smaller swf when loaded in a larger one?

Tags: actionscript, flash

I am making an interactive storybook project given these specifications:

[image]

My book has 13 pages, where 1 page = 1 swf loaded externally into the book swf. As you can see, the page swf must be centered in between the 2 buttons that are both 100x450 each. Whenever I try to load the swf, usually it's cut off at some point.

In short, how do I center my externally swf when loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the completeHandler Function like given bellow

```
function completeHandler(event:Event):void{         
    this.container.addChild(event.target.content);
    this.container.x = this.stage.stageWidth/2 - event.target.width /2;
    this.container.y = this.stage.stageHeight/2 - event.target.height /2;           
}
```

U can change this.stage.stageWidth with the center container width and apply same for width also

Comment: It worked better than what I went with, which was assigning the loader object itself the coordinated upon completion. Thank you sir gyandas!

Answer (score 0):

The advice gyandas gives is good. However, from the way you've worded your question I'm guessing you're already doing something along the lines of what he suggests. If so, you could try adding a filled shape of 520x450 as the background of each of your pages. You can set the alpha to 0 or match the background color of the book itself, but the important thing is to have some actual content of the required dimensions rather than relying on the supposed width of the SWF when centering it in another movie.

I'm not in a position to test this right now, but I seem to recall that the dimensions of a loaded SWF are calculated according to the bounding box created around actual content, and that I have resorted to doing this as a result.