# How to center swf loaded in a flash project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I want to load a swf file in my project as an intro.
I used the following code:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                    
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("intro.swf");
myLoader.load(url);                                   
addChild(myLoader);
```

How can I center the swf file?
I found almost the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888472/flash-actionscript-how-to-center-smaller-swf-when-loaded-in-a-larger-one), but it didn't help me!

Answer (score 0):

I take the code from the page you linked and add one line. This line means "when loader have loaded the file, run completeHandler function".

```
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void{         
    this.container.addChild(event.target.content);
    this.container.x = this.stage.stageWidth/2 - event.target.width /2;
    this.container.y = this.stage.stageHeight/2 - event.target.height /2;           
}
```

Comment: @user3400679 Do you have a "container" object? If you don't, it will not work. In that case replace the *this.container.addChild(event.target.content)* with *addChild(myLoader);* and the other *this.container* with *myLoader*.

Comment: @user3400679 Do you get any errors? If so, show us. If not - do you see the loaded clip once the load finishes?

Comment: @Fygo: No errors. I see the loaded clip but it's not centered.